# Shared instance accross inheritage

Tags: swift, inheritance

Say a framework provides customizable services through an open `class A`, that exposes a shared instance to use as follows:

```
open class A {
    public static let shared = A()
    open func aService() {} 
}
```

The regular usage of the service is as follows:

```
A.shared.aService()
```

**Important note:** the shared instance itself is also used from within the `class A` code or related code in the Framework.

Say you want to customize the service through inheritance, and you still want to keep the use of the shared instanced as follows:

```
override class B: A {
    public override func aService() {
        super.aService()
    } 
}
```

When you refer to the shared instance, unfortunately, it refers to the `class A` instance where you would like it refers to the inherited class instance.

```
B.shared.aService() // Failed!: This actually calls A.shared.aService()
```

One way to fix it is to make the construct as follows:

```
class A {
    public static var shared = A()
}
```

Then you are sure before any use of the service within you app, to change the instance as follows:

```
A.shared = B()
B.shared.aService() // OK! This actually calls B.aService()
```

Though the whole thing works, I would like to make it automatic and not rely on the initial line that changes the shared instance.

How would you do that?

**[CODE FOR PLAYGROUND]** that illustrates the goal to achieve and to help you better understand the question

```
open class A {
    public static var shared = A()
    open func aService() {
        print("\(type(of: self)): service (from A)")
    }

}

class B: A {
    public override func aService() {
        super.aService()
        print("\(type(of: self)): service (from B)")
    }
}

A.shared = B()          // Question : How to remove the need to this line, yet achieving the same functionality (and output)

A.shared.aService()
B.shared.aService()

// The output (which is correct) :
//B: service (from A)
//B: service (from B)
//B: service (from A)
//B: service (from B)
```

Comment: Not an answer but class A should be declared final so it can't be extended imo

Comment: Well, nope. I want A to be extensible though inheritance

Comment: 1) If possible, don't use inheritance for extension points. Use observables if you just need to be notified when certain things happen. Use a delegate pattern if you want to be able to change the implementation of a method completely. 2) You can have A be a final class and a singleton, which contains an `InnerA`. `A` delegates all operations to `InnerA`, which itself is subclassable. When a subclass is made, you can swap out the backing instance inside `A` with the new `InnerB`, but there's still only 1 instance of `A`, so that's transparent to the rest of the world

Comment: Sounds like a job for dependency injection. Not singletons.

Comment: Agreed; what you're describing here isn't inheritance. It's just global variables that happen to be namespaced via statics. This is not an appropriate way to provide customization points. Swift provides numerous better solutions (several described above). Delegate or pass in closures. "Inheritance-like" solutions are going to be fragile because it's not inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution, but...

I do, personally, agree with the other comments here. This *really* doesn't sound like a job for the singleton pattern.

In your current solution, you seem perfectly happy to overwrite the singleton instance mid-execution, which means it's *not* a singleton. There's only ever supposed to be one instance of a singleton, and if you can continually create and assign a new instance to the `shared` variable without breaking anything, then it's just not necessary to have this global state across your application.

However, for the record, you *can* achieve what you want with a `struct` that composes the static instances of each class, and which can detect the calling context and return the appropriate one each time `shared` is accessed:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    static var shared: ExampleProtocol { get }
    func service()
}

struct ExampleProvider {
    private static var a = A()
    private static var b = B()
    static func instance(type: ExampleProtocol.Type) -> ExampleProtocol {
        return type == A.self ? ExampleProvider.a : ExampleProvider.b
    }
}

class A: ExampleProtocol {
    static var shared: ExampleProtocol {
        return ExampleProvider.instance(type: Self.self)
    }
    func service() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func service() {
        print("Goodbye")
    }
}

A.shared.service() // Hello
B.shared.service() // Goodbye
```

So, yes, you can achieve what you want. But there's a pretty strong case for saying that you shouldn't...

Comment: Does not answer the question : both should return goodbye in your example. Plus that’s tons of code compared to my question.

Comment: Both do *not* return goodbye in my example. Run it. There is no answer to your question. You can't override something that is static, due to its very nature. It's like asking why my car can't fly even though I've fitted it with wings... You're trying to do something completely nonsensical.  There may be more code in my example, but the use of an interface decouples clients from your singleton classes, which is huge win over your preference for a spaghetti of dependencies.